# Error when trying to insert multiple rows of data from another table

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert into table2 multiple times. Into column1 I want to insert the same @foreignId as many times as there are rows from `select name from table1 where id = @id`

```
    Insert into table2(column1, column2)
    values(@foreignId, (Select name from table1 where id = @id))
```

I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   GO
   Insert into table2 (column1, column2)
   Select @foreignId, name from table1 where id = @id  
   GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` construct:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2)
SELECT @foreignId, name
FROM table1
WHERE id = @id;
```

I don't even know if SQL Server would accept a subquery of any kind in the `VALUES` clause, but even if it did, by your error message that subquery returns more than one row.  Using the suggestion about is one way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select should not used as subquery. You should try with following query.

```
Insert into table2(column1, column2)
Select @foreignId, name from table1 where id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Insert into table2(column1, column2)
Select @foreignId as foreignId, name from table1 where id = @id
```